# Why does this Google Charts API code work in a raw HTML file but not in a local Rails site page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I am using the following code successfully in a raw HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Month', '2010', '2011', '2012'],
          ['Jun',  3139285, 3266244, 3121214],
          ['Jul',  3531094, 3349940, 3214951],
          ['Aug',  3231183,  3406815, 3335187],
        ]);
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(
              data,
              {vAxis: {minValue: 500000, maxValue: 4000000}}
            );
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 450px; height: 250px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I try to employ the same technique in a Rails site page in the following manner, I can't get it work:

**index.html.erb:**

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Month', '2010', '2011', '2012'],
        ['Jun',  3139285, 3266244, 3121214],
        ['Jul',  3531094, 3349940, 3214951],
        ['Aug',  3231183,  3406815, 3335187],
      ]);
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(
            data,
            {vAxis: {minValue: 500000, maxValue: 4000000}}
          );
    }
  </script>
<% end %>
...
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 317px; height: 250px;"></div>
```

**application.html.erb:**

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= yield :head if yield :head %>
  ...
</head>
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong here. Is there something I am missing in regard to using the Google Charts API? I have read the documentation and can't find any reason as to why this won't work as it does in raw HTML file.

Comment: what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: also `yield :head if yield :head` looks strange to me. Shouldn't it be `yield :head if content_for?(:head)`

Comment: It's telling me that 'google' is undefined - probably because the javascript file isn't being sourced properly but I have no idea why. The JS is definitely being pulled into the head of the document.